# filesize is changing during download

Tags: javascript, php

i have a pdf file that if downloaded through the viewer it downloads at the correct file size but when i use this code for say download selected the file size of the pdf changes and renders it useless when you open with adobe/nitro/etc.

```
   <?php
   @apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
   @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $fullPath = $_GET['url'];
        if($fullPath) {
            @$fsize = filesize($fullPath);
            $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
            $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
            switch ($ext) {
                case "pdf":
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; 
                filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
                header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
                break;
                default;

                header("Location: ".$fullPath);
                exit;


            }
            if($fsize) {//checking if file size exist
              header("Content-length: $fsize");
            }
            fopen($fsize, "r");
            exit;
          }
      }
    ?>
```

i noticed the file size is 24kb on the server. i go to url and view it then click the download from pdf viewer the file downloads just fine and verified the filesize in my download folder at 24kb. however when i use this code above as my download.php it downloads but comes back as 2kb.

can someone help me figure out why its changing the file size please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the / in the url it was starting with. once i added a trim to the url it worked. tbh now that i started looking into this i dont think it really ever work just appeared it did.

```
$trmfullPath = $_GET['url'];

$fullPath = trim($trmfullPath, "/");
```

this seemed to fix it. also dont get any errors in my php error log now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code where you are actually sending the file.Make sure you actually send the file. You have used `fopen()` but you are not using `fread()` that's why files is getting opened but not getting being read  may be that's why it's showing some default output which amounts to 2kb . You can use the much simpler `readfile()` instead

For that replace this line

```
 fopen($fsize, "r");
```

with this one

```
 readfile('path/to/' . $path_parts["basename"]);
```

Just in case you are handling huge files like several MBs then fopen will suite you better as it would be more memory efficient.Also note the `b` flag in `fopen()` parameter it refers to binary mode so whenever you are sending a binary file like pdf,images etc you should always use this flag

```
set_time_limit(0);
$file = @fopen('path/to/' . $path_parts["basename"],"rb");
while(!feof('path/to/' . $path_parts["basename"]))
{
    print(@fread('path/to/' . $path_parts["basename"], 1024*2));
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

Comment: i tried this and still the same problem. it used to work all of a sudden it stopped. there is a javascript getting the file url from clicking a button and thats how this download.php knows where the file is. it continues to download the pdf file but only the 2kb.

Comment: function downloadFile(url){var iframe=document.createElement("iframe");iframe.src="download.php?url="+url;iframe.style.display="none";document.body.appendChild(iframe)}

Comment: try to echo the path of the file in php check if file is actually there in that path

Comment: i get an error in my php_error.log now.   fopen(/projects/52/test.PDF): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\downloadfile.php on line 26. i can verify that the file is there. also if i click on the file to view it in browser it loads no problem. then if i click the download icon in the pdf viewer it downloads just fine.

Comment: Its path related issue for sure , you should not take the `$fullpath` from `$_GET` rather just the filename and construct rest of  the full path yourself check this line `@$fsize = filesize($fullPath);` for value.

Comment: how if the code used to work just fine then suddenly it does not?

Comment: i even went back to 2016 backup to make sure the code did not change somehow and it has not. so im really at a loss here as to why it suddenly stopped working. also noticed it stopped working on other file extensions too. is there something i forgot to turn on in wamp? im sure it is something really stupid.

Comment: btw i apologize you were correct it was path related.